# Update Schema for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, upgradeschema

How do I write update schema in Magento 2 for the following:

```
$installer->run(
   "UPDATE {$this->getTable('catalog_eav_attribute')} SET `is_visible` = 0
   WHERE `attribute_id` IN(SELECT `attribute_id`
   FROM {$this->getTable('eav_attribute')}
        WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE 'my_name_%');"
);
```

Basically, I am trying to set `"is_visible" to 0` in `catalog_eav_attribute` table, if `attribute_code` is like `my_name_%` in `eav_attribute` table.

Comment: What's your Magento version?

Comment: Magento Version 2.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I needed:

```
        $connection =  $setup->getConnection();
        $where = $connection->select()->from(
            $setup->getTable('eav_attribute'),
            ['attribute_id']
        )->where(
            "attribute_code LIKE 'my_name_%'"
        );

        $connection->update(
            $setup->getTable('catalog_eav_attribute'),
            ['is_visible' => false],
            "`attribute_id` IN({$where->__toString()})"
        );
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Nice and precise answer +1 for that

Answer (score 1):

One of example of upgrade schema and data

Path should be like this: `app/code/Vendor/YourModule/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\YourModule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
 public function upgrade( SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context ) {
 $installer = $setup;

 $installer->startSetup();
 if(version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
 $installer->getConnection()->dropColumn(
 $installer->getTable('data_example'),
 'created_at'
 );
 }

 $installer->endSetup();
 }
}
```

Note: We have to check module version of in upgrade function. In this example we upgraded module from version 1.0.0 to 1.0.1. Drop created_at column from data_example table.

Path should be like this: `app/code/Vendor/YourModule/Setup/UpgradeData.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\YourModule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
 protected $_exampleFactory;

 public function __construct(\Magestore\DataExample\Model\ExampleFactory $exampleFactory)
 {
 $this->_exampleFactory = $exampleFactory;
 }

 public function upgrade( ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context ) {
 if ( version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<' )) {
 $data = [
 'title' => "The second example title",
 'content' => "The second example content"
 ];
 $example = $this->_exampleFactory->create();
 $example>addData($dalogta)->save();
 }
 }
}
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Will this update data in `catalog_eav_attribute`?

Comment: If your query is right, then it will definitely update whatever table you add in your query.

Comment: Have you resolved your query?

Comment: Yes, check my answer.